# Can i parse in ASPX-markup an int to an enumeration

Tags: asp.net

I read all entries from an entity Framework/DB for a web page (ASP.NET) and in a repeater on my page i set the value of a TextBox like that:

```
<td>
    <owiw:CustomTextBox runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ID="txt_FieldType" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "iFieldType") %>' />
</td>
```

To iFieldType exists an enumeration which lies in a static class.

Can i parse the int value using Enum.Parse?
Must be something like that, isn't it?

```
Text='<%# Enum.Parse(typeof(OneWhoIsWhoModel.Database.DatabaseHelper.CustomFieldTypes), (Container.DataItem, "iFieldType")) %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
I have forgotten to get the value with `DataBinder.Eval` and then it must be converted to the type string.
The solution is always simple, just the way to it is troublesome.

```
<owiw:CustomTextBox runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ID="txt_FieldType"
    Text='<%# Enum.Parse(typeof(OneWhoIsWhoModel.Database.DatabaseHelper.CustomFieldTypes),
    Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "iFieldType"))) %>' />
```